# Get the result of a subquery and join to it corresponding id column

Tags: mysql, join

How can I join the result of a sub-query with the outer query? If the question is kinda confusing below is the example:

```
Picture database
+------+---------+--------+
|  id  |  appId  |  name  |
+------+---------+--------+
|  1   |   33    |  1.jpg |
+------+---------+--------+
|  2   |   33    |  2.jpg |
+------+---------+--------+
|  3   |   33    |  3.jpg |
+------+---------+--------+
|  4   |   34    |  4.jpg |
+------+---------+--------+
|  5   |   34    |  5.jpg |
+------+---------+--------+
|  6   |   35    |  6.jpg |
+------+---------+--------+

article database
+------+--------+
|  id  |  data  |
+------+--------+
|  33  | Hello  |
+------+--------+    
|  34  | Hello  |
+------+--------+
|  35  | Hello  |
+------+--------+
|  36  | Hello  |
+------+--------+



my expected result
+------+---------+--------+------------+
|  id  |  data   |      picture        |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
|  33  |  Hello  | 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
|  34  |  Hello  | 4.jpg, 5.jpg        |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
|  35  |  Hello  | 6.jpg               |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
|  36  |  Hello  |                     |
+------+---------+--------+------------+
```

What the query do is join the picture and article together but store all of the picture into a corresponding article column.

**NOTE:** It is not necessary to seperate the name of the picture with "," but can be seperate the picture with white space or other symbol that will not conflict with the name of the picture.

I don't have any starting point so I can't provide any example of my query.But basically what I want is to know is it possible to acheive it?If yes then can anyone provide the query to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** for this

```
select
a.id,
a.data,
group_concat(p.name) as picture 
from article a
left join Picture p on p.appId = a.id
group by a.id
```